# Html/Css background and textbox problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just learning HTML/CSS and i have a little problem with the background and textbox i dont get why it isnt working
May someone tell me whats the problem and how to fix it? 
Greetings

i think there is something wrong with the overlays of the carousel but thats just guessing and filling this file with words to be able to porst it... i mean why is there such a high amout of words needed this is a short code i would rather only read the code instead of reading this long useless text...

```css
body
{
background-color: black;
}
#Haupt
{
  color: yellow;
    align-content: center;
}

.header1
{

}
h1
{
}
/* The navigation bar */
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
 
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
    
 overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
    margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
}
h1:hover
{
    background-color: dimgray;
}

 .tales {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
width:100%;
height: 10%;
max-height: 500px !important;
min-width: 1366px !important;
}


.textbox1 {
   position: abolute; /*position auf der Seite absolut */
   left:200px; /*position von links */
   top: 40px; /*position von oben */
   width: 300px; /*Breite der Box */
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   text-align: center;
   height: 300px; /*Höhe der Box */
   border: solid blue 1px; /* Rand durchgezogen blau 1px stark */
   padding:20px; /* Innenabstand vom Text zum Rand */
   background-color:#fff; /* Hintergrundfarbe */
   border-radius:15px; /* Ecken mir Rundungsradius */
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #000; /*schatten Ausrichtung links, oben,      Abstand von der Box, Ausdehnung, Farbe */
   opacity:0.8; /* Transparenz */
}

   
/*Nav bar*/
.main {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 980px;
 height: 10px;
    }
.links {
    float:left;
    
}
.rechts {
 width: 200px;
right: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
body {
 
 margin:0;    
 background-color: darkblue;
 }
 
 
 
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
 overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

</style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css">
  <h1>Bootstrap Example</h1>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 
 
<div clas="textbox1">
 <a>sdf</a>
</div>
 
 
<div class="navbar">
     <div class="main">
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#Dafuq"> DFUQ </a>
     <a href="#Dafuq"> DFUQ </a>
     <a href="#Dafuq"> DFUQ </a>
        </div>
        <div class="rechts">
          <a href="#Dafuq"> Fuchs Julian </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="Bild1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width = "100%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="Bild2.jpg" alt="Chicago" width = "100%" >
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="Bild3.jpg" alt="New york" width = "100%">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see that you are not seeing?

Comment: i expected to see a blue background and a coloured textbox... but nothing appears... the background is white and the textbox only a normal link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few spelling mistakes in place of `clas="textbox1"` use `class="textbox1"` and do few corrections as like below

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#Haupt {
  color: yellow;
  align-content: center;
}

.header1 {}

h1 {}


/* The navigation bar */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
}


/* Links inside the navbar */

.navbar a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Main content */

.main {
  margin-top: 30px;
  /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
}

h1:hover {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

.tales {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  max-height: 500px !important;
  min-width: 1366px !important;
}

.textbox1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/*Nav bar*/

.main {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 980px;
  height: 10px;
}

.links {
  float: left;
}

.rechts {
  width: 200px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: darkblue;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css">
  <h1>Bootstrap Example</h1>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



  <div class="textbox1">
    <a>sdf</a>
  </div>


  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="links">
        <a href="#Dafuq"> DFUQ </a>
        <a href="#Dafuq"> DFUQ </a>
        <a href="#Dafuq"> DFUQ </a>
      </div>
      <div class="rechts">
        <a href="#Dafuq"> Fuchs Julian </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="Bild1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="100%">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="Bild2.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="100%">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="Bild3.jpg" alt="New york" width="100%">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank u the Textbox works now... but still there is the problem with the background.... but theoretically it should work when this works... why cant i ever do somth. right...

Comment: @julianfuchs the spelling mistakes wont work. I am glad that it helped. Please accept and upvote if it is working

Comment: i upvoted i already but u wont see it cause i am new to stack

Comment: yeah i did already but stackoverflow sends me this "thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly "